# Некорректное перемещение рамки

Tags: c, winapi

Я новичок в программировании, пишу программу с нестандартным интерфейсом. Рамка окна в Windows 10 перемещается как надо, а вот в Windows 7 при перемещении левой рамки вправо остаётся след.

[image: некорректное перемещение рамки]

Весь код привести нереально в силу его размера, но вот несколько строк, которые отвечают за отрисовку окна:

```
SetWindowPos ( HwndGlavOkna,  HWND_TOP,  KoorGlavOknaX,  KoorGlavOknaY,  WirinaGlavOkna,  VysotaGlavOkna,  SWP_NOREDRAW )
InvalidateRect ( HwndGlavOkna,  NULL,  TRUE )
RedrawWindow (  HwndGlavOkna,  NULL,  NULL,  RDW_INTERNALPAINT  )
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём может быть ошибка.

Вот код отрисовки региона:

```
case WM_PAINT:
  hRgn = CreateRoundRectRgn (  0,  0,  WirinaGlavOkna,  VysotaGlavOkna,  20,  20  );
  if ( hRgn == NULL )    oNeizvOw;
  if (  SetWindowRgn ( IdGlavOkna,  hRgn,  TRUE )  ==  0  )    oNeizvOw;
```

Comment: А сам код отрисовки этого региона (в WM_PAINT) можете показать?

Comment: Вообще, если требуется такой код, чтобы перерисовать окно, значит что-то работает криво. Почему недостаточно обычного `InvalidateRect` или `InvalidateRgn`?

Comment: Возможно поможет флаг `RDW_ERASE` или его комбинация с `RDW_FRAME` (если Вы рисуете в неклиентской области -
 в ответ на `WM_NCPAINT`).

Comment: @mega добавил код отрисовки региона.

Comment: @mega не понял Ваш вопрос во втором комментарии. Вы имеете в виду убрать `RedrawWindow `?

Comment: @mega `WM_NCPAINT` не обрабатывается.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61296/discussion-between-0zerro-and-mega).

Comment: @mega я исправил ошибку. Смотрите в ответе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне удалось исправить ошибку, заменив флаг `SWP_NOREDRAW` на `SWP_SHOWWINDOW`:

```
if (  SetWindowPos ( HwndGlavOkna,  HWND_TOP,  KoorGlavOknaX,  KoorGlavOknaY,  WirinaGlavOkna,  VysotaGlavOkna,  SWP_SHOWWINDOW )  ==  0  )    oNeizvOw;
```